# How to delete only variables created by a specific matlab script

Tags: matlab

Is there some way to delete only the variables generated in a matlab script at the end of the script and not any other variables of the workspace which are not generated in the script?

Note : The script is not a function.

Basically I want to do the following in **one line**

```
save abc.mat    % saves the whole workspace
some_script     % call the script
clear           % deletes the variables created by the script along with the whole workspace
load abc.mat    % again loads the whole earlier workspace
```

Comment: Would `some_script` clear the workspace?

Comment: Use `structures` for the 'to-delete'-variables.

Comment: After the edit, now your title and the comment - `deletes the variables created by the script along with the whole workspace` contradicts I think or at least is confusing.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding , I thought you were asking about the piece of code I have written in the question. I will remove the comment. And YES , I want `some_script` to delete the variables it created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`who`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/who.html) before the script, then after the script; compare the results ([`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)) to detect variables created in the script, and then [`clear`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/clear.html) only those.

Variable names `varsbefore`,  `varsafter` and `varsnew` in the following code should be guaranteed not to be used before the script or within the script.

```
varsbefore = who; %// get names of current variables (note 1)
some_script
varsafter = []; %// initiallize so that this variable is seen by next 'who'
varsnew = []; %// initiallize too.
varsafter = who; %// get names of all variables in 'varsbefore' plus variables 
%// defined in the script, plus 'varsbefore', 'varsafter'  and 'varsnew'
varsnew = setdiff(varsafter, varsbefore); %// variables  defined in the script
%// plus 'varsbefore', 'varsafter'  and 'varsnew'
clear(varsnew{:}) %// (note 2)
```

Notes about the code:

1. `who` used with an output argument returns a cell array of strings containing the names of all variables.
2. The functional form of `clear` is used, with input arguments in the form of a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) generated from a cell array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `structures` of variables in this way:

```
FOO_STRUCT.foo_var = var_from_abc.mat + rand(1); 
FOO_STRUCT.foo_var2 = 10*log10(FOO_STRUCT.foo_var);
FOO_STRUCT.foo_var3 = FOO_STRUCT.foo_var2 + var_from_abc.mat;
```

The upper case part is the `structure` name. The lower case part is the `variable`.

You can use variables from the workspace in your script, make your work and at the end of the script you delete the entire `structure`

```
clear FOO_STRUCT
```

Comment: If there are lot of variables in the workspace then it would take a lot of lines to assign each variable to the structure. In that case it may be better to use the syntax I mentioned in the code. I just want a short command.

Comment: you don't have to assign each variable to the structure. Structures can use the variables in your workspace without problems. Just insert in the structure the variables that you want to use for your calculations and that you want to delete later

Comment: I am saying that to insert each useful variable in the structure `FOO_struct`, it would take a line of code per variable. If there are a lot of variables that I want to use then that may be a problem. Also,I will be duplicating my variables which may be a problem in case of limited memory.